# Java Servlet if statment don't need { } brackets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am a beginner and reading through Murach's Java Servlet and JSP...  Going through the examples.  Kind of stuck at this Ch11 simple shopping cart example.
I would post the whole code here but its really way to long.

I have put the full code on my dropbox link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36625850/Ch11-JSTL.rar

Questions:

1. CartServlet.java

   ```
   if(quantity > 0)
       cart.addItem(lineItem);
   else if(quantity == 0)
       cart.removeItem(lineItem);

       session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
       String url = "/cart.jsp";
       RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);

       dispatcher.forward(request, response);
   ```

   This is probably a dumb question.  I notice for servlet If statement you don't need { }?  Why is this? I mean regular java if statements all require { } so why is the servlet any different?
2. cart.java

   ```
   public void addItem(LineItem item)
   {
   String code = item.getProduct().getCode();
   int quantity = item.getQuantity();
   for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
   {
       LineItem lineItem = items.get(i);
       if (lineItem.getProduct().getCode().equals(code))
       {
           lineItem.setQuantity(quantity);
           return;
       }
   }
   items.add(item);
   }
   ```

What I can't follow is `item.getProduct().getCode();`. I am not really sure what would this output.

Comment: your post subject suggests you have a question about {} brackets. Your post suggests you have a question about how item.getProduct().getCode() is used. Which is it?

Comment: "I mean regular java if statements all require { }". No they don't.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans both if you know how... If not its okey as well.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Servlet is also java code and rules that are applicable to core java are applicable to Servlet too.
{} are used to combine number of statements into single block.
ex.

```
if(condition)
  statement 1;
  statement 2;
```

In above example statement1 will get executed only if condition evaluates to true.Statement 2 will not be part of `if` statement so it gets executed as normal statement.

```
if(condition)
{
  statement 1;
  statement 2;
}
```

Now in above example as you have enclosed statement1 and statement 2 in `{}` whole block will be part of `if` and both statement will get executed only if `if(condition)` evaluates to true.

2)`if (lineItem.getProduct().getCode().equals(code)`

In above statement `lineItem.getProduct()` returns `product` object.
So `lineItem.getProduct()` becomes `product.getCode().equals(code)`.Now `product.getCode()`  returns code object.So  `product.getCode().equals(code)`  becomes `code.equals(code)` And if both are equal then `if` evaluates true.

Comment: Ohhh i think i start to see it now... Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

if-else clause (and all other control structure) read by block in java.

So if you put

```
if(x>2)
System.out.println("a");  ==> this is the next block
System.out.println("b");

if(x<2)
{        ==> this is the next block
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println("b");
}
```

So testing above code if x == 1 ,

```
in first if statement 
prints --> "b"
in second if statement
prints --> "a"
           "b"
```

Another example

```
if(x>2)
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)  --> next block of if
       for(int j=0;j<200;j++){  --> next block of first for
           if(x>0)
             Sysout("a");  --> next block of if
            else
             Sysout("b"); --> next block of else
       }
```

In Java it's recommended always use braces.

For your second question

`item.getProduct().getCode();`

item is `LineItem` object.

Your class sure is

```
public class LineItem{

private Product product;

public Product getProduct(){
return product;
}


}
```

Product class

```
public class Product{

private String code;

public String getCode(){
 return code;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look through the codes and answering them.

1. I had the {} but it wasn't outputting anything.  After your explanation I realize I put the {} at the wrong place.  thank you

2. Even though item is 'LineItem' it can access Product class method?

Comment: @EricHuang technically class method are static method, you may mean methods that you enter with an object, item can access to public products method cause item `HAS A` product. This is call composition.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you don't use any {} in if it will execute the first statement after it. If you use a {} it will execture the all statements withing {}

For example

say `condition` is true

```
if(condition)
   sttmnt1;   // it will execute this only
sttmnt2; // this is out of if block
```

and in the following case both sttmnt will be executed

```
if(condition){
   sttmnt1; 
   sttmnt2; 
}
```

So in your example

```
if(quantity > 0)
    cart.addItem(lineItem);
else if(quantity == 0)
    cart.removeItem(lineItem);
```

In both if and else if condition there is only one statement. So it is not necessary to use {}

1. to know what `item.getProduct().getCode();` will return, check what class object is returning in the getProduct method of `LineItem` class. in the returned objec't class type check whet is the return type of `getCode()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Servlet Java code is just regular Java code. Your `if` without brackets would work the same way in regular Java.
2. Your `LineItem` class has a method `getProduct` whose return value is an object that has a `getCode` method. What this code snippet does is compare the value of `getProduct().getCode()` of all entries in `items` with the one of the given item. If any of them match, the function breaks and returns. So in short, this method makes sure that there is only distinct values of `getProduct().getCode()` are in the `items` collection.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that `{}` makes multiple statements appear as one block.

Sort of like statement grouping.

So when you just have one statement you don't really need the `{}` but when you have multiple statements the `{}` are useful.

I however use the brackets all the time even for one line statements because for me it looks pretty :-)

Comment: =D  I did use the `{}` but it wasn't working.  Well, it wasn't working because I didn't put `{}` at the right spot... Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

if statement is same for all.
There is no separate  (Java Servlet if statement).

If there is only one statement to execute(when [if,else if,else,while,for]) satisfies  , we no need to use {}(but not recommended,readability problem occurs )

ex:

```
  if(condition){ 
   System.out.println("hai"); // here only one statement is there to execute
   }
```

is same as

```
    if(condition) 
   System.out.println("hai");
```

Similarly

```
   int i=1;
  while(i++!=10){
  System.out.println("hai"); 
     }
```

is  same as

```
       int i=1;
  while(i++!=10)
  System.out.println("hai");
```

In Java only switch statement requires {} even though it has single case statement

Comment: Else if statement is else without braces then if.. is not an atomic statement is the same like doing else{if(){}} if you put braces

Comment: you can write else{if(){}} as else if(condition){any number of statements, if only single statement brackets are not required }